# "Intercept" the opening of any tooltip appwide

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I want to show the text of a tooltip of any control in my wpf app inside a status bar, when a tooltip is about to be opened.

Of course I could try to loop recursively through all child controls of the main window and
set their `ToolTipOpening` event to always the same method. But is there an easier way ?

Something like a `Application.Current.AnyToolTipOpening` event ?

Answer (score 9):

Sure, try this:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement), FrameworkElement.ToolTipOpeningEvent, new ToolTipEventHandler(ToolTipHandler));
```

That registers a handler for all classes that derive from FrameworkElement.

Your handler method might look like this:

```
   private void ToolTipHandler(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e) {
        // To stop the tooltip from appearing, mark the event as handled
        e.Handled = true; 
        FrameworkElement source = e.Source as FrameworkElement; 
        if (source != null) {
            MessageBox.Show(source.ToolTip.ToString()); // or whatever you like
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks , that worked. Additionally,to make the statusbar text disappear when the mouse leaves the control with the tooltip :

```
 EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement),
                  MouseLeaveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(ClearText));
```